# Emulate card reader

Tags: c#, winapi, c#-4.0, pcsc, winscard

I'm doing a project in C# using winscard.dll to communicate with a smart card. Right now I'm don't have a card reader to test with, so I'm working on basic PInvoke layer right now, but I cannot test it because I don't have a smart card service running. And now the question:

Is there a way to emulate a smart card(reader) on Windows so that is visible from the winscard api?

Comment: I'd advise you to read this - http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/net/smart-cards-in-net/